# Difficulty in understanding the CBS-inequality proof.

Tags: inequality, proof-verification

[image]

---

I can't understand why the discriminant has to be negative here. *Could someone please elaborate*?

Comment: I would say the discriminant is _non - positive_ rather than negative.

Comment: Naturally, but could you explain why that follows from f(x)>=0 for all x part of R ? @thanasissdr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the polynomial $f(x) = Ax^2 +B x+ C$. There are $3$ cases for the discriminant.

- $D>0 \iff 2 \text { distinct real roots } x_1, x_2, \text { with } x_1 < x_2$. The sign of $f$ is the same as the sign of $A$ on the interval $(-\infty, x_1)\cup (x_2,\infty)$, while the sign of $f$ is the opposite of the sign of $A$ on the interval $(x_1,x_2).$
- $D = 0 \iff 1 \text{ real root } x_0 .$ The sign of $f$ is the same as the sign of $A$ on the interval $(-\infty, x_0) \cup (x_0, \infty)$.
- $D< 0 \iff \text { no real roots }$. The sign of $f$ is the same as the sign of $A$ on $\mathbb R$.

---

$f(x) \begin{array}[t]{l}= Ax^2 + Bx + C = A \left(x^2+\frac BA x +\frac CA\right)=A\left(x^2  +2\cdot \frac BA x +\frac{B^2}{4A}-\frac{B^2}{4A^2}+\frac{4AC}{4A^2} \right)\\
=A\big[\left(x+\frac{B}{A}\right)^2-\frac{B^2-4AC}{4A^2}\big]=A\big[\left(x+\frac BA\right)^2-\frac{D}{4A^2}\big].
\end{array}$

Thus, the sign of $f$ basically depends on $D$, since $\left (x+\frac BA\right)^2\ge 0, \forall x\in\mathbb R.$

- $D = 0 \iff f(x) = A\cdot \underbrace{\left(x+\frac BA\right)^2}_{ \ge 0}$
- $D < 0 \iff f(x) = A\cdot \underbrace{\big[\left(x+\frac BA\right)^2-\frac{D}{4A^2}\big]}_{>0}$

Comment: Why is the sign of f the same as the sign of A on R? Because the Disc. becomes complex right? +1

Comment: Could you please wait for a while?  I will edit my answer to include the part you are asking.

Comment: Sure; no problem!

Comment: Answer edited. It's a kinda compact, but I hope it makes sense.